# LinkedIn API stopped functioning in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, linkedin-api

We had built widgets for LinkedIn in Salesforce (Force.Com) Enterprise Version Environment using their API which has stopped working from some time. It is causing major Inconveniences for the affected users. Kindly share if similar issue has been noticed at your end and a fix for it.

Here are the steps we performed till date:

1. After achieving the successful authentication using Oauth 2.0,we are using “people search” for the LinkedIn search functionality.
2. Response we were getting , when we were making a GET request for the people search API:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
   <error>
       <status>403</status>
       <timestamp>1433254195523</timestamp>
       <request-id>PY4LJUNDOX</request-id>
       <error-code>0</error-code>
       <message>Access to people search denied.</message>
   </error>
   ```

Comment: Several of LinkedIn's APIs are not longer available to the public, as noted in their blog post from Feb 12th:  https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/posts/2015/developer-program-changes

If you're a partner with LinkedIn, you should get in touch with your support contact there, otherwise, that functionality is likely no longer available to you.

Answer (score 0):

**Starting from [May 12, 2015](https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/posts/2015/developer-program-changes), Linkedin has limited the open APIs. 
Access to `Groups` requires that you apply for and are granted access to this information from LinkedIn.**

The following endpoints are available for general use:

- Profile API — /v1/people/~
- Share API — /v1/people/~/shares
- Companies API — /v1/companies/{id}

If your application is currently using any other API services (e.g. **Connections, Groups, People Search, Invitation, Job Search**, etc.) you will have to apply to become a member of a relevant Partner Program that provides the necessary API access to continue to leverage any of the endpoints that are not listed above.

Check out this [link](https://developer.linkedin.com/support/developer-program-transition) for the list of API changes that were announced.